# Python: Memory-Efficiency of Assigning Variables and Calling Methods

Tags: python, memory

This has been bugging me for a while. I'm wondering about the comparative memory-efficiency of assigning variables and calling methods. Consider, for example:

> s = "foo"
>   x = s.lower()

Versus

> x = "foo".lower()

Which one of these is more efficient in terms of memory use?

This is obviously a trivial example, but it illustrates what I'm wondering about.
There are many instances in which we define some variable `var1 = foo`, and then define a second variable `var2 = var1.method()`. Does this total process require more memory than just defining `var2 = foo.method()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bytecode is larger in the first case, but only by a trivial amount.

```
$ python3
Python 3.3.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 08:10:50) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dis
>>> def f():
...   s = "foo"
...   x = s.lower()
...   return x
... 
>>> def g():
...   x = "foo".lower()
...   return x
... 
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('foo') 
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (s) 

  3           6 LOAD_FAST                0 (s) 
              9 LOAD_ATTR                0 (lower) 
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            0 (0 positional, 0 keyword pair) 
             15 STORE_FAST               1 (x) 

  4          18 LOAD_FAST                1 (x) 
             21 RETURN_VALUE         
>>> dis.dis(g)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('foo') 
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (lower) 
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            0 (0 positional, 0 keyword pair) 
              9 STORE_FAST               0 (x) 

  3          12 LOAD_FAST                0 (x) 
             15 RETURN_VALUE         
>>>
```

(It's sad that CPython *still* doesn't do even basic CSE or copyprop at byte-compilation time, but that's a whole 'nother question.)

The runtime memory requirement is also slightly larger in the first case, because the function has two variable slots instead of one, but the string itself is not copied an extra time.  Python consistently uses reference semantics for everything.

**EDIT:** as cdonts points out, if the code is more complicated and the variables don't immediately go out of scope, the first version keeps the original string alive on the heap until `s` does go out of scope, which *is* potentially a significant extra memory cost.  I hadn't even thought of that.

Comment: Excellent answer. So this holds generally, as well?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean by "Python consistently uses reference semantics for everything."  In your `var1 = foo` scenario, `var1` and `foo` will both point to the same object on the heap.

Comment: Ah, yes. I was wondering if there might not be some inefficiency in assigning a variable, like a pointer mechanic of `var1 -> foo -> heap_object` rather than just `foo -> heap_object`. That answers it; thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example `s` is still in memory until the garbage collector deletes it, so your second example is more efficient in terms of memory use. However, considering that's a very very little portion of the RAM, in many cases it's better to go for readability (the first example looks better).

Hope this helps.